# Docker commands are suddenly hanging on Debian

Tags: docker, debian

I have a Debian (5.10.92-1) machine running docker (20.10.12) and there are roughly 15 or so containers.

It was working perfectly until yesterday but is now exhibiting some really odd behavior:

- Upon reboot everything seems to work
- When inspecting containers, the ones that require outgoing connections sometimes appear stuck. Just stuck, no errors in the log, etc.
- I see some DNS resolution errors in the logs: external DNS udp:4.2.2.2 did not return any AAAA records for "fapi.binance.com.""
- The host has no problem reaching the domain
- The daemon.json has two DNS servers setup
- There is over 400gb free on the disk

When I try to see the log of a stuck container:

- sometimes I can see it
- sometimes the command just hangs and I need to close that terminal.
- I use the UI tool 'dry' to inspect containers, etc; sometimes, it loads and works, sometimes it loads and I can see a container's log but it'll freeze when trying to restart the containers and sometimes the tool freezes on load.

When I try to kill a container:

- sometimes it'll kill it.
- sometimes it'll hang and eventually the container is gone; from then on, many commands will just freeze.

I pruned all files, etc and it didn't change anything.

When I try to restart the Docker daemon:

- sometimes it'll restart it
- sometimes the command will timeout

This is really odd, inconsistent, new and sudden.

Where should I look at?

Comment: Are there any useful errors in the log from the docker daemon itself?

Comment: No, nothing at all. When I tails the logs and I do some operation that will lock, nothing gets printed